Installing MS SQL Server ODBC Driver on Ubuntu 24
How do I install the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC drives on a Ubuntu 24 OS running on an intel 64bit system?

Check out his article; https://medium.com/@imakhileshwar/install-microsoft-sql-server-on-linux-ubuntu-5c9d3d3038b0

Microsoft maintains up-to-date documentation on how to do this including what versions of Ubuntu are supported here.  If the instructions below don't work (which were taken from this documentation linked), you should refer to this documentation.

As of October 3rd, 2024, the time of this posting, Microsoft has provided commands in a script to execute.
For Ubuntu 24.04, you can do the following though:
# Get signing key for repository from Microsoft
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/microsoft-prod.gpg

# Obtain the configuration for the repositories and add it to the system.
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

# Update package lists
sudo apt update

# Install MSSQL ODBC driver version 18
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18

If you need the tools that go with this (sqlcmd and bcp) you can install them after the above by also doing the following:
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc

You can also install the development headers (needed for some things to compile to USE the driver) with this in addition to the above:
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

